# PyCharm remote interpreters

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm 2.1 Early Access Preview [link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2012/03/pycharm-2-1-early-access-preview-package-and-environment-management/#comments)

We have new feature: Remote interpreters – full integration with Python interpreters running on remote hosts;

**How use it?**

I have 2 machines:

1. W7x64 ip 192.168.1.147 - pycharm 2.1
2. Ubuntu ip 192.168.1.4 - python, ssh, celery, django etc (vmware virtual machine)

In W7 Pycharm:

[image]

I try code:

```
from celery.task import task
@task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

ssh://echeg@192.168.1.4:/usr/bin/python2.7 -u C:/Dropbox/my_py/opoveshun/tests/celery/tasks.py
/usr/bin/python2.7: can't open file 'C:/Dropbox/my_py/opoveshun/tests/celery/tasks.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: check your run config ... it should not contain the windows path but the path of the script on the ubuntu machine

Comment: Set a path mapping from local paths to remote in your run configuration.

Comment: @DmitryTrofimov I have the same problem. I set up path mapping but it looks like PyCharm ignores it/forgets it - that is: a) i still have error with my local path b) when i open settings screen mapping is missed.

Comment: Does that happen in latest PyCharm 2.5.1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote debugging on pycharm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919165/remote-debugging-on-pycharm)